# Generic class that extends class and implements interface

Tags: java, android, generics

To reduce dependece of class, I want to send parameter (using generic class) to constructor that extends some class and implements interface, for example

```
public interface SomeInterface{
    public void someMethod();
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements SomeInterface{
    //implementation
}

//here is classs, that I need to create. T must extend Fragment and implements 
//SomeInterface. But, I'm afraid, if I'll use MyFragment directly, it will create a
//dependence of SomeClass from MyFragment.

public class SomeClass /*generic?*/ {
    public SomeClass(T parent);
}
```

Is it possible?

Futher, using my T class, I want to create views, using T.getActivity() as Context.

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Using Java reflection you can pass a `Class` object into a method and inspect it for its implemented interfaces via `getInterfaces()`, as well as obtain/call a `Constructor` to make a new instance.  But your specific use case is unclear, so it's difficult to figure out how to piece these items together to solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

> T must extend Fragment and implement SomeInterface

In that case you could declare `SomeClass` as the following:

```
public class SomeClass<T extends Fragment & SomeInterface>
```

That would require an object of type `T` to both extend `Fragment` and implement `SomeInterface`.

> Further, using my T class, I want to create views, using T.getActivity() as Context.

I'm unfamiliar with Android, but if `getActivity()` is a public instance method declared in `Fragment` then will be entirely possible to call it on an instance of `T`, since the compiler will know all `T`s must inherit that method.

Comment: How would you use Mockito to create a mock class that is of type T?

Comment: @bwicks Good question. I suspect your test class might need to declare a type like `abstract class TestFragment extends Fragment implements SomeInterface` and then mock that type with `TestFragment.class`.

Comment: This is so incredibly unintuitive, thanks. ^^'

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
class SomeClass {}

interface SomeInterface{
    public void someMethod();
}

class AGenericClass<T> extends SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    public void someMethod() {}
}
```

This is allowed.

But what's Android specific about your question? I think I must be missing something so can you provide some more details?

*update below*

I'm still not totally sure what you want to do, and I'm also not sure you need to worry about the dependence right away, but this is also legal, using [bounded type parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html):

```
interface SomeInterface{
    public void someMethod();
}

class Fragment {
    public void aMethodInFragment() { }
}

public class SomeClass <T extends Fragment & SomeInterface> {
    public SomeClass(T parent) {
        parent.someMethod();
        parent.aMethodInFragment();
    }
}
```

The type parameter `<T extends Fragment & SomeInterface>` specifies that `T` should be a subclass of `Fragment` and implement `SomeInterface`.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy if i understand you correct you to have some type T which is extending Fragment and implementing some interface. So you have to write something like that.

```
abstract class TemplateFragment extends Fragment implements SomeInterface{}
```

and then in your classes

```
class SomeClass<T extends TemplateFragment> {
...
}
```

It will do the trick.

Comment: It works but not if your subclasses need to implemented a different kind of "Fragment" for exmaple when instead of Fragment we want to use View here.

So subclasses could be a CustomView extends LinearLayout implements SomeInterface

Since LinearLayout is a View the condition is still true when using

BaseClass<T extends View & SomeInterface>

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin you can use such syntax:

```
class MyClass<T> where T: AnotherClass, T: SomeInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin equivalent would be:

```
class SomeClass<T>() where T: Fragment, T: SomeInterface
```