# Java inheritance Ambiguity?

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I was asked this in an interview I couldn't find the solution so I thought it to take to you guys. 
We have methods in interface i. Just consider method1. So we write the code for method1 and reuse it in all three class A, B & C. We don't do anything with X, y & Z. So I thought to make different class D to define method1 and write code under it but then D can't be extended to A, B & C since they extend X, Y & Z

Any suggestions?
Note: If we are using Specifically JDK 1.6

```
 interface i {
      method1();
      method2();
}
class A extends x
class B extends y
class c extends z`
```

**EDIT:**
Classes `x`, `y`, and `z` cannot be altered.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it is horribly unclear.  Please try to use clear English with grammar that approximates to correct English grammar.  Please also include all relevant requirements in the Question itself.  (Saying in comments on Answers: *"oh, I actually meant this, and that"* is wasting everyone's time. )

Comment: I made a small edit to hopefully make it more clear.  Unfortunately, the wording you have given makes it hard to understand.  Please edit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this:

```
class A extends x implements i {

}
```

See:

[Generic class that extends class and implements interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871285/generic-class-that-extends-class-and-implements-interface)

---

If, on the other hand, you really want code (not just the function prototype) that is shared by A, B and C, then X, Y and Z should extend from a class `Parent` (X, Y and Z would have to be derived from a class Parent).

Then `method1` can be defined in `Parent` and not in x, y and z.

Comment: Im sorry I didn't explained it correctly at first but I edited the question. Feel free to comment if I have not made anything clear.

Comment: Hi - you may already know this - can someone explain why an interface required if the purpose is to share code?  Code cannot be defined in an interface.  Where is the code that is supposed to be shared across A, B and C (it cannot be a part of the interface).  Thanks

Comment: Yeah , Interviewer told me you have  method defined under interface i. How will you use code of method1 without writing code again in Class A, B And C.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not 100% clear, so I am going to attempt to answer this and explain my interpretation.  Please let me know if the interpretation is wrong so I can point you in the right direction:

First of all, you say that all classes need `method1()`.  Assuming `method2()` is needed as well, classes `A`, `B`, and `C` need to `implement` this interface.

Your code will then look like this:

```
class A extends x implements i { ... }
class B extends y implements i { ... }
class C extends z implements i { ... }
```

If the same implementation of `method1()` is needed in classes `A`, `B`, and `C`, then I would recommend using an  abstract class instead, thus `i` would look like:

```
abstract class i {
    method1() { 
        // implementation here
    }
    abstract method2();
}
```

Because Java only allows one super class, `x`, `y`, and `z`, would need to extend `i`, thus making `A`, `B`, and `C` look like:

```
class A extends x
class B extends y
class C extends z
```

**EDIT:**

Classes `x`, `y`, and `z` need to look like:

```
class x extends i {
    // implement method2 here
}
class y extends i {
    // implement method2 here
}
class z extends i {
    // implement method2 here
}
```

If method2() only needs one implementation as well, do this:

```
class i {
    method1() {
        // implement here
    }
    method2() {
        // implement here
    }

}

class x extends i {}
class y extends i {}
class z extends i {}
```

***EDIT 2:***

Without editing classes `x`, `y`, and `z`, Stephen C posted a very good solution:

```
class D implements i {
    method1() {}
    method2() {}
}
class A extends x implements I {
    D d;
    method1() {
        d.method1();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right but method1 will have same code in all the 3 classes I dont want to write that code again and again for A,B and C.

Comment: Given you don't want to rewrite code, use an abstract class as I have outlined in my answer.

Comment: If I make abstract class D and implement interface i to write definition of method1 . Can I extend class D in A, B & C since hey already extends X, Y & Z? Will there Not be ambiguity problem?

Comment: X, Y, and Z will need to implement D.  If `X`, `Y`, and `Z` do not implement `method2()`, they themselves will need to be abstract.  I do not believe you will need `D` to implement `i`, assuming `method1()` and `method2()` are declared in `D`.

Comment: sorry my bad, The aim is we don't do anything with X,Y & Z but method1 will have some code which is needed in A B & C.

Comment: See Stephen C's 2nd solution.  It appears that will solve your problem.

Comment: Im sorry this was my first question on StackOverflow. I think I have made some edits which will clear the things.

Comment: Do any of these solutions solve your problem?  As it has been written, the solutions provided by myself and other users should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no requirement to share the code:

```
public class A extends X implements I {
    ... // implement method1 here, or inherit it from X
}
```

If you need to share code, there are three possible approaches:

1. Add `implements I` to the relevant classes and change `X` etc to `extend` a base class that implements `method1()`; e.g.

   ```
     public class A extends X implements I{ ...
     public class X extends Q { ... }
     public abstract class Q implements I { ... /* implement method1() */ }
   ```
2. Use delegation; e.g.

   ```
     public class A extends X implements I {
         private I eye = // something that implements the I API

         public void method1() {
             eye.method1();
         }
     }
   ```
3. In Java 8 and later, put the implementation of `method1()` into the interface `I` as a `default` method.  This *won't* work with Java 6<sup>1</sup>.

None of these approaches work in all circumstances.  If none of them work (and there are no other alternatives) then you need to duplicate code.

---

<sup>1 - But on the other hand, I would think twice about working for a coding shop where they are stuck on Java 6.  That suggests they have "issues" in the way that they manage things ... which could make life unpleasant for a Java developer going forwards.  (And why would an interviewer state that restriction anyway.  Surely they want to recruit someone who can cope with modern Java as well as ancient Java.)</sup>

Comment: OP said JDK 6, so the third solution would not work.

Comment: I know that.  I read that too.  That's what I specifically stated the precondition.  It is worth mentioning that solution *even though it doesn't work for the OP's specific use-case*.

Comment: Actually what he meant was , we are not doing anything with x,y and z. We write the definition of method1 and resue that code in A B & C

Comment: There is nothing in the Question that says that.  I am answering the Question **as you have written it**.  But see approach #2.